# Trigger on Account object for tracking sales reps and their territories

Tags: apex, trigger

My accountCreation trigger is as follows:-

```
trigger accountCreation on Account (before insert, before update) {
    //Store all Zip Codes in a SET
    SET<String> zipCodes = new SET<STRING>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore) {
            for(Account newAccount : Trigger.new) {
              zipCodes.add(newAccount.BillingPostalCode);  
            } 
        }
    }
    //Find changed Zip Codes
    LIST<ACCOUNT> updateAccount = new LIST<ACCOUNT>();
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore) {            
            //SET<ID> changedAccount = new SET<ID>();
            for(Account changedAcc : Trigger.new) {
                String oldZip = Trigger.oldMap.get(changedAcc.Id).BillingPostalCode;
                String newZip = changedAcc.BillingPostalCode;
                    if(newZip != oldZip) {
                    zipCodes.add(newZip);
                    //changedAccount.add(changedAcc.Id); 
                    updateAccount.add(changedAcc);              
      
                }   
            }    
        }
     //Query for Territory__c records matching the set of Zip Codes
    //and storing the query results in a MAP
    MAP<String, Territory__c> terrMap = new MAP<String, Territory__c>();
    LIST<Territory__c> zipMatch = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerID, Zip_Code__c
                                   FROM Territory__c
                                   WHERE Zip_Code__c IN:zipCodes];
    for(Territory__c terr : zipMatch) {
        terrMap.put(terr.Zip_Code__c, terr);
    }
    //Iterate over the Account again for those Accounts
    //with changed Zip Codes and look for associated
    //Territory via Zip and assign the Account's OwnerId
    //field to the value of that Territory's Owner__c field
    for(Account iterAccount : updateAccount) {
        Territory__c lookTerr = terrMap.get(iterAccount.BillingPostalCode);
        if(lookTerr != NULL) {
             iterAccount.OwnerId = lookTerr.Owner__c; 
        }
    }
  }

}
```

When I update an account I am getting following error:

> BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Territory__c.Owner__c: Trigger.accountCreation:

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. So how do I go about. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Storing data does not require a trigger. What functionality are you seeking that would require a trigger? (Please [edit] to clarify).

Comment: I just want to store Zip Codes with their respective sales rep's name in the database with the Owner field as a lookup to the User

Comment: Please **[edit] your post** to clarify. Again, storing data does not require a trigger.

Comment: Vijay, have you actually searched for "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field" ? It's a pretty common error and an easy fix, despite the wording being a little odd "without querying the requested field" basically says what the problem is and suggests how to fix it.